# Accessing dynamically created element with selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stumbled upon trying to select newly created element with classic jQuery selector, minimal example:

```
var el = $("<input class='form-area' id='myTest'></input>");
$("#myElement").append(el);

// works fine
el.val("80");

// what I'd like to do
$("#myTest").val("80");
```

As I am pretty unsure why desired selector doesn't work on the newly created element I've tried to access the elements after I am sure that they have been created successfully:

```
MyAppendFunction().promise().done(function() {
    $("#myTest").val("80");
}
```

Since I need to create multiple inputs like that and the number of them varies (rows for tables) it would be very nice if I could select them with jQuery selector instead of having to store references to them in a list.

Comment: Your code works fine as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/rtbv475g/. One reason this would not work is if you have multiple elements with the same id of `myTest`. In that case you need to create unique ids, or use a class.

Comment: Also note that `append()` is a synchronous operation, so trying to return a promise from it is a redundant overcomplication.

Comment: I made sure that the ids are unique. I'm creating elements after ajax call can that change something?

Comment: You need to ensure you call `val()` in the callback where you are appending the new HTML, then it will work. Could you edit the question to show a more complete example of your JS, including your AJAX call

Comment: I've tried to select the element and do something trivial on it like $("#myTest").fadeOut() just to see whether selecting works. I'll edit the question, thanks for your replies, appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly iterate over the -elements you add to your DOM, so use an index to give them a unique ids like:
YOURLOOP {
...

```
id = `myTest-${YOURINDEX}`
var el = $("<input class='form-area' id='" + id +"myTest'></input>");
..
}
```

To acces any of these -elements, just use the element (a clicked button, anchor,.. ) to get the "sibling, parent, next, " element with an id beginning with "myTest": 
$('#yourrferenced-element').next("[id^='myTest-']").attr('id') to get its id an than do what you want to do with it.

Comment: In comments you can read that all ids are unique. +rep for trying to help.

Comment: All right. I edited my answer: I didn't see the comments as I was writing my answer.

Comment: The code is pretty heavy, I'll just stick to the list references.

Comment: I think you were able to give the <inputs>-elemens you added to the DOM unique ids. The problem is hoq to access any of tem right? But we need your scenario: when do you have to identify the right one of them? after a button/anchor click?

Comment: don't worry I'll figure it out somehow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192038/discussion-between-matj-stagl-and-meziane).